# receiving this study error randomly !! "Modify_study_limit_exceeding" in tradingview

Tags: pine-script, back-testing

When I am trying to optimize my strategy in tradingview, I keep receiving this error totally randomly!!
study error: "Modify_study_limit_exceeding"

what I am doing is changing the parameters with a selenium app and in the middle of the process, the error rises, and when I change one of the inputs it continues. It appears on random inputs. I mean I can't reproduce the error by entering the same inputs, it just appears randomly.

I couldn't find any description for the error and I didn't even find any related topic on google so I am here asking for help. thank you :)

Comment: I have a tool I created at tradingtools.software which is easier than selenium if you ever wanted to try it for optimizing inputs.  I'm adding a feature today to refresh on these warnings so it continues safely, it also adds random time delays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatization and optimization via external software, tools, bots and extensions are prohibited on TradingView. All TradingView features are for manual use only.

From [Terms of Use, Policies and Disclaimers](https://www.tradingview.com/policies/):

> you may not use any data mining, robots or similar data gathering and extraction tools on the TradingView content, frame any portion of TradingView or its content, sublicense, assign, transfer, sell, loan, or otherwise distribute for payment the TradingView content without our prior written consent. You may not circumvent any mechanisms included in the TradingView content for preventing the unauthorized reproduction or distribution of the TradingView content.

That's why there is such an error.
BTW, there is a risk to get a  ban, if you keep breaking the rules.